# Query returns Date (YYYY-MM-DD) and want to display as Friday, Oct 15

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that is grabbing the Date of a given post. I'm displaying this information in a chart that has the date and number of posts for that day. How can I display "Friday, Oct 15" instead of 2010-10-15??

Query:

```
$oct_week = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*), DATE(`dPostDateTime`) AS `day` FROM `tblQA` WHERE dPostDateTime >= '2010-10-01' AND dPostDateTime <= '2010-10-31' GROUP BY `day`");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`dPostDateTime`), '%W, %b, %e')
```

Comment: date_format() can take a datetime value directly, no need for the date() function in there.

Comment: correct, but he had already wrapped it with DATE() so I wasn't sure what the column was.  Just being consistent.